# Django: select_related with multi table inheritance

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have the following model structure:

```
class A(models.Model):
    prop_a = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class B(A):
    prop_b = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class C(A):
    prop_c = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class D(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey('A')
```

So essentially, I have a model (`D`) which has a foreign key to an 'abstract' model (`A`) which is subclassed by `B` and `C`.

Now, when I run `D.objects.all().select_related()`, only the properties of `A`are queried. I assume this is because at query time, Django does not know which child class the `fk` is an instance of (and neither do I in my current structure).

Is there any way to query the properties of the child class without changing the model structure?

I also tried prefetch_related and tried using an InheritanceManager from [django-model-utils](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils), both to no avail.

**Edit:** To clarify, I am looking for a way to iterate over objects of `D`, accessing the concrete values of `fk` (which are either `B` or `C` objects) while only hitting the database once.

Running `D.objects.all().select_related()` produces the query

`'SELECT "mapping_d"."id", "mapping_d"."fk_id", "mapping_a"."id", "mapping_a"."prop_a" FROM "mapping_d" INNER JOIN "mapping_a" ON ("mapping_d"."fk_id" = "mapping_a"."id")'`

Let's say one of those is an object `d` of type `D` whose property `fk` is of type `C`.

Now, when I access the value `d.fk.c`, Django runs an additional query to get the properties of C:

`'SELECT "mapping_a"."id", "mapping_a"."prop_a", "mapping_c"."a_ptr_id", "mapping_c"."prop_c" FROM "mapping_c" INNER JOIN "mapping_a" ON ("mapping_c"."a_ptr_id" = "mapping_a"."id") WHERE "mapping_c"."a_ptr_id" = 3'`

I want to avoid this additional query per object of D. Using an InheritanceManager in the proposed way does not seem to do that.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Inheritance Manager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) usualy and runs as expected.

1) Remember to set the inheritance manager on `A`:

```
class A(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = InheritanceManager()
```

2) Make the right query:

```
some_d_object = D.objects.get( pk = 1 )
related = some_d_object.fk.all().select_related()
```

Noticte than, your query `D.objects.all().select_related()` will returns `D` objects. Nobody inherits from `D`, then, no subclasses, just `D` objects.

3) Enjoy inheritance.

**Edited** I edit this quetion becase the OP comment.

> With this pattern, Django performs an additional DB query when I access the related object. Since I have many D objects, this gets quite expensive. Do you know if there is any way to fetch them all at once? –

Ok, le'ts try to write an answer, because I really don't understand exactely witch objects OP is looking for. Question is fine because he has written almost [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but I don't know expected values, Let's try with some samples.

1) If you want all objects, as easy as:

```
all_objects = A.objects.all().select_subclasses()
```

2) If you want to filter, then, do it. I write a sample:

```
filtered_objects = A.objects.filter( d__pk = 1 ).select_subclasses()
```

3) Get all subclasses, and also, `D` class, in a single query:

Unfortunatelly you can not apply `prefetch_related` (may be you can but I don't know how to do it). Then you need to massage data with itertools.

```
all_objects_and_D = list(
                     A
                     .objects
                     .select_related('D')
                     .select_subclasses()
                     .order_by( 'D__pk' )
                     )
#at this point use itertools to massage your data
keyfunc = lambda x: x.D
data = [  { k, list(g) } 
          for k, g in 
          itertools.groupby(all_objects_and_D, key=keyfunc )
       ]
```

Comment: With this pattern, Django performs an additional DB query when I access the related object. Since I have many D objects, this gets quite expensive. Do you know if there is any way to fetch them all at once?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I think I left it a little bit unclear what exactly I am trying to do, I updated the question accordingly.
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Silvester, my bad. I mixed `select_subclasses` and `select_related`. Now I have fix it. Sorry.