# how to use prefetch_related or select_related with multitable inheritance

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-orm

hey guys i have these models

```
class Product(models.Model):
     .......
class Course(Product): 
     .........
class Book(Product):
     .........
class Cart(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

what I want is to prefetch the products with the Cart objects i know we can do this

```
Cart.objects.select_related('product')
```

but how do we also get the product to children too without making an impact on the performance
and if i get it's children how can get it's child when accessing the product like:

```
cart_instance.product.its_child
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
Cart.objects.select_related('product').select_related('product__its_child')
```

Refer this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: but how can i access it's corresponding child since i have course and book @msvstl

Comment: @th3plus did you read this? [should-i-avoid-multi-table-concrete-inheritance-in-django-by-any-means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466577/should-i-avoid-multi-table-concrete-inheritance-in-django-by-any-means)

Comment: Check whether this solves your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53341978/13779320

Comment: yeah i did read this before, is it better to use content_type and generic relationship instead of multitable inheritance? @msvstl

Comment: @th3plus It's based on your requirement, check [what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-genericforeignkey-vs-multitable-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562039/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-genericforeignkey-vs-multitable-inheritance)